# Cell repeating data after 3rd cell when we add new cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on an image editing iPhone application. I am using `UITableView`. My problem is that when I insert new rows into the table view, the new table view cells after the 3rd cell repeat the data of the 1st cell.

I have to do lot of searches and unfortunately couldn't find the solution. Can anyone view my code and tell me where I've gone wrong?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    VerticalFrameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[VerticalFrameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.imgView.image   = nil;
        cell.tf_Comment.text = nil;
    }

    //add gesture on picture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *imageTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHandlert:)];
    imageTap.delegate    = self;
    [cell.imgView addGestureRecognizer:imageTap];
    //add pinch gesture for zooming image
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinchRecognizer =
    [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                              action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
    pinchRecognizer.delegate        = self;
    [cell.imgView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];


    //add pan gesture for plcing text
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *moveText = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveTextOnImge:)];
    moveText.delegate       = self;
    [moveText setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [moveText setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [cell.tf_Comment addGestureRecognizer:moveText];




    cell.imgView.tag            = indexPath.row+6000;
    cell.sclView.tag            = indexPath.row+7000;
    cell.btnAddText.tag         = indexPath.row+8000;
    cell.tf_Comment.tag         = indexPath.row+9000;

    return cell;
}
```

**// add new cell code here**

```
- (IBAction)btnAddNewCell_Action:(id)sender {
    if (objectsArray.count<6) {// not add more then six cell 
        [objectsArray addObject:@"Other's"];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:objectsArray.count-1 inSection:0];
        [tbl_Frame insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tbl_Frame  scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }else{
        [AppUtility displayAlertWithTitle:AlertTitle AndMessage:@"You can't take more then six images"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Tableview is reusing old cells thats the only reason. Remove else keyword and then try

Comment: I edit my code with your suggestion but same problem is occurring.

Comment: In your btnAddNewCell action wht you are passing objectsArray.count-1 this ??

Comment: In this line only passing the  index path last row of tableview with next we will add new row.

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath where are u setting the image ? You should set the image & tf_Comment label...

Comment: my cell repeat again from first to third cell when i add cell max then 3

Comment: Are you sure it's the cells repeating and not just the same images being displayed in different cells? What does the code look like that sets the images on the cells?